# Ionic2 menuToggle is not working after Modal.present

Tags: ionic2, angular2-modal

My side menu or menu toggle code is in the app.compnent.ts. This menu toggle is working perfectly in all the pages before I click Modal.  MenuToggle is not working after I click the button for Modal. I'm not sure what is the exact issue. Any suggestions please?

Menu:

```
<ion-icon name="menu" menuToggle float-left margin-right></ion-icon>
```

PageA:

```
pageBModal() {
  let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(PageB);
  modal.present();
}
```

PageB:

```
  closeModal() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashBoardPage);
  }
```

Comment: Could you please create a **[Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/)** where we could reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use MenuController

```
import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController) {
 }  
     If you want to close menu please use close() event

      this.menuCtrl.close()

     If you want to open menu please use open() event

      this.menuCtrl.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I have faced the same issue.

I have fixed this by using `Events`.

If you try to navigate page from modal, You will face with above issue.(Side menu will not work). Instead of navigating from `modal ts`, Try to navigate from `parent ts` by using `Events`.

Eg :

```
Parent ts :

events.subscribe('modal:finished', (page) => {

    if(page == 'yourpage') {
      this.navCtrl.push(YourPage);
    }

  });
```

Modal ts :

```
this.events.publish('modal:finished', 'yourpage');
```

You can send from modal where you need to redirect after modal dismiss. Based on this condition you can redirect wherever you want.

Hope it will help someone.